# A way to check if wordpress installation is self-hosted or hosted via wordpress.com?

Tags: hosting

I'm developing this plugin that needs a way to check the status of the Wordpress installation
What is the most reliable way to determine that?

Any $_SERVER variables or anything that could differentiate between the two?

Comment: I'm curious: why does it matter? If it's because something will or won't be available then you could test for that specifically. I could believe there are WordPress.com mu-plugins the same as WPEngine install, but I don't know any specifics.

Comment: And by "check the status" you mean the same as your question title, whether it's hosted on WordPress.com or not? Or something else?